How to prove the spectrum of $B$ interlaces its diagonal enteries.
\begin{equation*}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & -1 & -1 & \dots & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & d_2 & -1 & \dots & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & d_3 & \dots & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & \dots & d_{k-2} & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & d_{k-1} & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & d_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Assume that the order of matrix is even, that is $k$ is even and $d_{i}'$s are positive integers. Let, $\lambda_{1}\geq \lambda_{2}\geq \dots\geq \lambda_{k}$.
we know (by software) that the spectrum of $B$ satisfy this interlacing property, that is  $\lambda_{k} \leq d_1 \leq \lambda_{k-1} \leq 
 d_2 \leq \dots\leq \lambda_{\frac{k}{2}} \leq d_{\frac{k}{2}}$,  and    $d_{\frac{k}{2}+1}\leq\lambda_{\frac{k}{2}-1} \leq d_{\frac{k}{2}+2} \leq \lambda_{\frac{k}{2}-2} \leq \dots \leq d_{k-1} \leq \lambda_{2} \leq d_{k} \leq \lambda_{1}$. My question is how to write its proof that the spectrum of $B$ satisfies the interlacing property.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

“we know (by software) that... $\lambda_{k} \leq d_1 \leq \lambda_{k-1} \leq d_2 \leq \dots$”. How is that possible? What if $d_1>d_2$?

where, $d_1<d_2<\dots<d_k$.
